# The kernel of a function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f:G \to G'$ be a homomorphism. Let ker $f$ denote the kernel of $f$.Let $x$ $\in$ ker $f$ .Does this imply $x$ is the identity of $G$?Give a counterexample if the proposition is not true.

Can anyone  help ?I was proving a group theory problem when suddenly looking at my work I thought whether the above is true.I know that the converse is true....

Comment: This is a self thought question and I was not able to make anything out of it

Comment: Its a doubt....

Comment: Any non-injective homomorphism is a counterexample. Also as an exercise you can try to prove that if $x\in$ ker $f$ implies $x=1$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any group $G$ the unique map $f:\ G\ \longrightarrow\ \{e\}$ is a group homomorphism, so the  proposition is not true.